# How to pass by reference to another object's method in VC++ (error C2664)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

After using lovely C# for years, my C++ skills suffered a lot, but I'm confident to get back on track with your great help.
Passing a value by reference to a method WITHIN a class works:

```
// WORKS
class Foo {
  void FooAdd(int i, int j, int &k) {
    k = i + j;
  }
  void FooDo() {
    int i = 20;
    FooAdd(1, 2, i);
    std::string s = std::to_string(i) + " (3: SUCCESS; 20: ERROR)";
    std::cout << s;
  }
}

int main() {
  Foo* foo = new Foo();
  foo->FooDo();
  return 0;
}
```

If this method is moved to another class, VC++ cannot compile the file anymore:

```
// error C2664: "void Bar::BarAdd(int,int,int *)" : Konvertierung von Argument 3 von "int" in "int *" nicht möglich
// error C2664: "void Bar::BarAdd(int,int,int *)" : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'int' to 'int *'
class Bar {
  void BarAdd(int i, int j, int &k) {
    k = i + j;
  }
}

class Foo {
  void FooDo() {
    int i = 20;
    Bar* bar = new Bar();
    bar->BardAdd(1, 2, i);    // error C2664
    std::string s = std::to_string(i) + " (3: SUCCESS; 20: ERROR)";
    std::cout << s;
  }
}

int main() { // unchanged
  Foo* foo = new Foo();
  foo->FooDo();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I assume that `BardAdd` is a typo? It makes no sense that this code would be producing the error you show.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `;`s after the class declarations are missing too.

Comment: I suggest creating an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and I would wager in the process you will find the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the typos, it is just a simplified example of my code to demonstrate the issue. In the real code base each class has it's own file, just as VisualStudio creates them by default. In my first code, class Bar was a static lib project in the same solution, in my second code it is just a different class within the same project. Error C2664 remained.

Answer (score 0):

If you correct the typo, add the missing semi-colons, include iostream, and make the methods public, it will work. See https://ideone.com/lWDpbl

```
#include <iostream>

class Bar {
public:
  void BarAdd(int i, int j, int &k) {
    k = i + j;
  }
};

class Foo {
public:
  void FooDo() {
    int i = 20;
    Bar* bar = new Bar();
    bar->BarAdd(1, 2, i);    // error C2664
    std::string s = std::to_string(i) + " (3: SUCCESS; 20: ERROR)";
    std::cout << s;
  }
};

int main() { // unchanged
  Foo* foo = new Foo();
  foo->FooDo();
  return 0;
}
```